# Accessing only some pieces of data from a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a userinfor model which has name, userinfo_id, user_id. I have a user model with user_id. I have a video model with video_id,name, userinfo_id and user_id. So If a user uploads a video, and his user_id is 5, and userinfo_id is 10, the video model info will be as follows: Video_id: *some number*, name: nameofvid, userinfo_id: 10, and user_id: 5. Now that the relationship is explained, I am displaying all the userinfo data and video on the index page. I have a small search bar in my index page too, so my controller index function looks like this:
My userinfos controller index function:

```
def index
  @userinfors = Userinfo.where(["name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
  @myvideo = Video.where(:user_id => @userinfors.user_id)
end
```

When I run this, I get the following error: 
[image]
*The line 6 they are referencing is the "@myvideo = ...." line in the index function.*

My index view:

```
<%= form_tag userinfos_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "search" %>
<% end %>

<div>
    <% @myvideo.each do |myvideo| %>
        <div>  
            <%= video_tag myvideo.introvideo_url.to_s, :size => "240x160", :controls =>true %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <% @userinfors.each do |userinfor| %>
                <div>
                    <% if userinfor.user_id == myvideo.user_id %>
                        <p><span>Name: </span> <%= userinfor.name %> </p>
                        <p><span>College: </span> <%= userinfor.college %> </p>
                        <p><span>GPA: </span> <%= userinfor.gpa %> </p>
                        <p><span>Major: </span> <%= userinfor.major %> </p>
                        <%= link_to "profile", userinfo_path(myvideo.userinfo_id) %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
        <% end %> 
        </div>
    <% end %> 
</div>
```

@userinfors gets all the records where the name of the record matches the name entered in the search bar. This part works. So let's assume there are 100 records. 10 of those are named THOMAS. Then when THOMAS is entered in the search bar, @userinfors will have 10 records in it, right? Because only 10 are named thomas. That means those 10 records have different individual user_id's. Then what I want to happen is, the program will go through the 100 video records, and if the user_id in that video record matches the user_id in one of the 10 @userinfors records, that video will be added to the @myvideo variable. So at the end, @myvideo will have 10 records. The user_id's of the ten records in @userinfors will be equal to the user_id's of the ten records in @myvideo. This is what I want to happen.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userinfos
  has_many :videos

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :videos, through: :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
    end
end
```

Video model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :introvideo, VideoUploader 
end
```

Comment: This is unreadable - can you edit this to clearly state what problem you are trying to solve and what the desired outcome is? And include the relevant models. I'm guessing that what you are looking to do is a join and set conditions on the joined table. `@videos = Video.joins(:userinfos).where("name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%")`.  
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Start by describing in broad terms - `I want users to be able to search ..., given ... they should see ... `

Comment: @max Sorry about that. I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing to an `ActiveRecordRelationship` to get the `user_id` attribute, to do it you need to access to an specific object within that relationship.

You're using the result of a `where` statement that's an `ActiveRecordRelationship` to create another query passing that object. You should iterate over every element inside that relationship, but isn't an action to be performed within a controller.

You could create a helper, in `app/helpers/userinfos_helper.rb` which receives the `user_id` and returns all the video that have that `user_id` as value, maybe:

```
# app/helpers/userinfos_helper.rb
def video_by_user_id(user_id)
  Video.where('user_id = ?', user_id)
end
```

Then in your view, you can get the `user_id` when you iterate over the `@userinfors` and pass it to your helper:

```
# app/views/userinfos/index.html.erb
<% @userinfors.each do |user| %>
  <% video_by_user_id(user.user_id).each do |video| %>
    <%= video.path %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I get that. That's what I want. I need many records, not one. Because I am iterating over it in my index view. Check my question, I added the index view to it.

Comment: Hey bud, as you can see in my index view code shown in the question, I have written the code in such a way that will display the information of the user right under the video of that user. Will your code do that too? I want to display the video, the under it the information of user, then the next video an user information under it and so on

Comment: It worked! You have been helping me out a lot. Thank you! Would you be interested in paid part time work?